# asp.net core radio button helper renders always the same id for each radio button

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Create.cshtml**
// Rest form code removed for brevity

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount">
    <input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="true" type="radio" />Yes
</label>
<span asp-validation-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" class="text-danger" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount">
    <input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="false" type="radio" />No
</label>
<span asp-validation-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" class="text-danger" />
</div>
```

**Created Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount">
    <input value="true" type="radio" data-val="true" data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;HalfScoresCount&quot; ist erforderlich." id="GradingKey_HalfScoresCount" name="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" />Yes
</label>
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount">
    <input value="false" type="radio" id="GradingKey_HalfScoresCount" name="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" />No
</label>
<span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
</div>
```

Why has the generated html the same id for both radio buttons?

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Though doesnt answer your problem straight, you can use htmlhelpers and override the constructor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why has the generated html the same id for both radio buttons?

By default, the `id` field for an `input` will be the name of the property set in the `asp-for` tag helper value. You've got the same value listed twice:

```
<input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="true" type="radio" />Yes
<input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="false" type="radio" />No
```

> How can I avoid that?

Simply specify your own `id` attribute values:

```
<input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="true" type="radio" id="myFirstId" />Yes
<input asp-for="GradingKey.HalfScoresCount" value="false" type="radio" id="mySecondId" />No
```

As long as you do not modify the `name` attribute, the model binding will still function properly.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about id/name changes but good you clarified it.

Comment: Note that specifying an explicit `id=""` attribute on the `<input type="radio" />` may break `<label for="">` elements, for example - or anything using `@Html.IdFor( m => .. )`.